# custom outlook reminder addin or VBA

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010, vba, microsoft-outlook-2013, reminder

I cannot count how many times I missed my meetings appointment because I Was so deep into my programming work. I wonder if anyone has a quick/easy solution where it will halt my entire monitor red (or something like that) x minutes prior to the meetings. I think I tried to write a VBA that will be bright and grand so I won't missed it but I failed to have it working.

my issues with the default outlook reminder is that it can easily goes to the background unnoticed.
I need it to be more "in your face" alert if possible

I used both outlook 2010 and outlook 2013.  both have exactly the same reminder behaviour. 
Any tips from the pros?

Thank you